# Composing custom components using autolayout

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am using custom components using autolayout (and using CompactConstraint). Those components works perfectly well, until I nest them one with another.

Let imagine that I have a ProfileContainer that is displayed inside a SettingsView. That ProfileContainer wraps content that can gives an height according to its constraint (for example at least to contain the image embedded inside it), though if I do not hard code some height for that ProfileContainer in my SettingsView, its height is set to 0. I don't get why and how to solve this.

I think I correctly configure my ProfileContainer calling:

```
profileContainer.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

I think it could be linked to content hugging and content compression resistance but I am unsure of that.